# Custom switch button?

Tags: android

I am using a switch button in an android studio activity.What I want to do is that when I slide from left to right,in the right side to appear a timer,and in the thumb part of switch button to have an image.Too a need it to not appear the track part before starting sliding the thumb!How it is possible to make that?

Comment: change the visibility of timer and image programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

as Anjal Saneen said in the comments, you can set the visibility programmatically. You can call your switch and then set visibility for your components like so:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    myTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

});